# Function of distance to a moving object

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, kinematics

I have few problems, I'll try to split them in an understandable way. If you are good at linear algebra, could you take a look at the second part? (Both questions are clickable links.)

(1)
[Two objects are situated at a arbitiary distance from one another. One is immobile (A), one is moving (B) at a constant velocity (Bv). What is the distance (d) between them at a given time?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2bEM.png)
The distance can be a scalar or a vector, either one helps. Thanks!

(2)
[Two same objects, but at a given time, B wants to move straight toward A with a certain speed (a). We want to find the vector (V) along which we apply the acceleration force](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ8Wx.png)
Think: I'm a rocket inside an asteroid formation, in a few seconds I'd like to move straight towards THAT asteroid. Which direction should I face and how long should I use my thrusters?

[PS 1] The function is meant to be used by computer script, so try to go easy on usage of square roots :)

Comment: Hint for (1): You have to describe $B$'s position as a function of time (that's easy), then you may take distance of the two objects, which is simply the Euclidean distance of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Hint for (2): If you can already describe $B$'s position as a function of time, you know where $B$ is located at the moment "when it wants to move towards $A$". The vector towards $A$ can then simply be calculated as the difference in the coordinates of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now :). Could you alter your question to describe the situation better? Furthermore, what's $d(t)$?

Comment: @DavidČepelík Now to think about it, I'll try it. Thank you. The d(t) is the funtion of distance over time (it has a "hat" because it is a unit vector - length of 1)